# Parsing a .CSV file and populating the data in XML

Tags: c#, xml, csv

I am trying to display a real time graph using the data which is coming from a device attached to a external source, the data coming from the device will be a .csv file, now i want to use this data and populate the content in an XML file and display the graph with XML datasource. Is it good doing it using XML or i should go for MySQL database keeping performance in mind? And After parsing the .CSV file line by line, how do i populate the data in XML in C#? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not create a small transport object designed to model the contents of the incoming CSV lines.  Once you have your CSV information stored in the transport object, you can just serialize each object to XML.

Comment: Why use XML ? And why use SQL ? It seems that you are merging 2 different issues which are storing data AND displaying it. The 2 processes can be separate & independent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV --> XML?

Actually XML is used to store hierarchical data, a CSV file is simply a table so why don't you go for MySQL instead? And yes, writing and parsing XML is not that good when it comes to performance.

Comment: Well is there a way where i can just take the data and send it to the graph using xml without creating a new .xml file. I am new to c# so i dont know how do i go for it?

Comment: Your aim is to display real time data so I don't recommend XML. Even if you use LINQ to query data from XDOM objects this is no match for querying an SQL database at all.

Comment: @arpitbajpai : Why do you need XML to graph data ? There are many other straightforward ways

Comment: @MikaJacobi: because i am thinking about storing the data coming from device in XML files.

Comment: XML is a data interchange format but it's not itself a database so don't use it like one. Use XML for transformation and transmitting of date, but use SQL for storage and searching of data.

Comment: As stated before, If I were you I would disassociate displaying from storing. You should give more details about the data and the display. If you have CSV, store it a CSV. or DB if you want/need to query or process the data. Concerning the display you have many options depending on your needs. Be more specific